# Time Series Regression

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

[image: Image shows estimated point (by eyeball) at which maturity may occur]I am looking to identify when a significant change occurs across a series of growth rings (annuli) of fish pectoral fins. I am trying to identify when the annuli width decreases (state of maturity). I will have the widths of each growth ring (um) across the structure.

After I determine the state of maturity I want to compare the trace elemental compositions before and after. I have ablated a line to quantify 13 trace elements across the fin ray from the core to the outer edge, ensuring a
consistent and distinguishable signature corresponding
with each growth band. I am considering using an interrupted time series regression to compare before and after maturity. Does this sound like a good way to go?
[image: example of trace elemental profiles across the fin ray]

Third image shows [image: same as image 1 (different fish)]

Comment: Since this is a domain I know nothing about, please pardon the ignorance implicit in this question.   Does the onset of the state of maturity occur gradually over several years or relatively abruptly?   The implication of the latter is that the annuli width decrease occurs over perhaps two observations, which is easier to detect than a slow decrease would be.